# can nt partition free space while installing Ubuntu in a windows machine to dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

i am trying to dual boot Ubuntu with windows 10 in a uefi bios. so when i enter into installation it shows my existed ntfs partitoins and some free space. when i click free space and add button (+ button) is still shows dim so how can i partition the free space ? can i partition the free space in windows and again boot installer media install in that partition ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you haven't install Ubuntu, is that correct?
If that so, my suggestion, boot Ubuntu with LiveUSB (try Linux, do not install yet), then open gParted software in the application list, I though that's already included in Ubuntu 14.04 upward. If not, type

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Then, just create new partition with that free space, and use 'ext' as partition type, it would be better to use 'ext4', why? See [What is the difference between ext3 & ext4 from a generic user's prespective](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44908/what-is-the-difference-between-ext3-ext4-from-a-generic-users-prespective/44911#44911)

Or,

If you want to create that new partition, I suggest to use 'EaseUs Partition Master' software, it's free and featured.

As note with dual boot issue, turn off your 'secure boot' in BIOS, and disable 'fast startup mode' in your windows.
Control Panel --> Power Options --> Choose what the power button does.

It's a must!
And optionaly you might need to disable hibernation, by open your cmd (as admin), and type :

```
powercfg.exe -h off
```

See [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) for more documentation about dual boot Ubuntu and Windows.