# Can't install Ubuntu, stuck on "Updates and Other Software"

Tags: system-installation, budgie

I'm stuck trying to install Ubuntu, I can use the live desktop but when I go to install it just never gets past the Updates and Other Software screen. The cursor spins and I've left it a good hour but nothing happens. I've successfully installed using the same USB drive on my laptop but my desktop won't have it.

I've tried minimal install, normal install, with 3rd party options and without. I've made sure secure boot isn't enabled too.

I've also tried Budgie with also gets stuck at the same place.

Specs:

i5-3570
16gb RAM
GTX 970

1tb HDD
5X 120GB SSDs (not RAIDed)

Is there anything I can try?

Comment: can you post the screenshot of where your installation hangs?

Comment: I can't post it here from my phone because of the file size but here's the screen where it hangs: https://imgur.com/a/5VIg197. - I know that's Budgie but it's the same screen in regular Ubuntu too

Comment: Three years later and this is still a problem without a solution. Do Ubuntu devs ever read Ask Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

I opened `gparted` and saw there was a NTFS partition which was corrupted, that's why the installer didn't proceed. I deleted that partition and the installer worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 4):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1766978

It's to do with this bug here.

When the installer got stuck, I opened Disks and mounted/unmounted the Windows partition a few times until it got to the next screen. Had to manually set up partitions because Ubuntu didn't detect Windows but it's all installed now.

Comment: This is what worked for me aswell. How many times is "a few times"? I ended up mounting the partition 5 times or so (just spammed the button). But in reality it should probably be enough to do it once? Would have tested if I had more time

Answer (score 1):

For my case, when I cancelled the installation, I was directed to use Ubuntu on the live bootable flash disk.

1. I opened the terminal and run

   ```
   # fdisk -l
   ```

to list all detected hard disks.

Here is a picture of the Terminal window:
[image: fdisk -l output]

2. Then I decide to format my hard drive because it had no important data.

   ```
   # mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda
   ```
3. I ran the installer again and it worked.

Here is a picture of the Terminal window:
[image: mkfs output]

Comment: why not ext4? ext3 has far less features and is much slower [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44908/what-is-the-difference-between-ext3-ext4-from-a-generic-users-perspective)

Comment: True, I realize ext3 was slow. I was being specific to what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to unplug all HDD disks except the SSD where system is going to be installed. After that installation went to the next step in a few seconds while before I was waiting for around an hour without result and HDD was in heavy use.

Answer (score 0):

while installing dont connect to the internet and uncheck 'download updates while installing budgie', probably its taking time because its downloading updates....you may download the updates after the installation is finished

Comment: Because there's no network connection, the update box is greyed out

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm a solution similar to what Gabriel posted - but in my case, neither disks program nor gparted was able to actually delete the corrupted partition at the beginning.  I had to actually delete partition from the terminal (using one of the terminal commands that deletes) and then the terminal hung.  When I closed terminal and then opened up conventional program...I was able to work with the partition. The original corruption occurred because I had installed a previous linux distribution that screwed up the partition so it would not delete in a conventional way.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say if you have windows partition which you don't want to format and you are getting this error while trying to install latest ubuntu flavors, try to start the installer from boot in safe graphics mode. Then try to install. The "updates and other softwares" screen might hang for 10 mins, but after that you should see disk partition screen, here do the partition appropriately as per your choice. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to install Ubuntu as dual boot next to Windows, I had the same problem. I had to turn off hibernate on Windows with `powercfg -hibernate off`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue like this:

1. Quit installer where it hangs
2. Open Gparted, view the existing drives
3. Close Gparted, making no changes
4. Launch the "Install Ubuntu 20.04.4.LTS" file from the UI desktop
5. Continue the installation as before
6. Make it past the previous lockup window
7. Resize the partition when prompted...
8. Install complete.

Comment: Hello. If the comment is part of the answer you need to edit the answer and include it not have it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying to remove the windows hibernation file manually.

See something like https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+question/701505.

I did this by:

1. Using Gparted from a live USB stick.
2. Starting a terminal while in Gparted live.
3. Doing something like:

   - `sudo ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdb1 /path/to/mount`
     where you would replace `sdb1` and `/path/to/mount` with values suitable for your disk situation
4. Exiting Gparted
5. Immediately running the linux installer (i.e., before booting windows again and letting it mess up the disks)

Answer (score -2):

Well this worked for me:
Show applications -> Gparted -> Right Click on the drive partition on which your windows is installed delete it and then your installation won't get stuck

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.